# How to change observable.timer to setInterval?

Tags: observable, angular5

I want to change the observable timer to  setInterval:

```
this._timer = Observable.timer(0, 1000).subscribe(() => {
   this._timerAction()
});
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
this._timer.subscribe(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
         this._timerAction()
    }, 1000);
});
```

But it is not working. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Could not completely understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide more details?

Comment: I want to run every 1-second _timerAction. In other functions, I have got `this._timer.unsubscribe()` so I need here subscribe. I wrote my solution in answer, and in other functions, I change `unsubscribe` to `clearInterval(this._timer)`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in this way:

```
this._timer = setInterval(() => {
        this._timerAction()
}, 1000);
```

and I deleted Observable with subscribe.